# Sorting Algorithms with dictionary

Tags: python

I think I may not understand the use of dictionaries with the bubble sort algorithm. I'm not sure how to sort the diction in the list is it by key? or items? I've heard that sorting a dictionary is possible if this is true then I will have to think of another way of doing this. Any suggestion would be helpful.

The program is supposed to take the name of a student and 3 grade gets the average then add them to a list. At the end of each while loop, the list is sorted and displayed this is where the error occurs.

```
    listA = []
    listB = []
    listC = []
    listD = []
    
    i = 1
    
    def list_organizer(record):
        if 75 <= total <= 100:
            listA.append(record)
            print("It's in A")
        elif 50 <= total <= 74:
            listB.append(record)
            print("It's in B")
        elif 25 <= total <= 49:
            listC.append(record)
            print("It's in C")
        elif 0 <= total <= 24:
            listD.append(record)
            print("It's in D")
        else:
            print('Error!, The grades you’ve entered are invalid.')
    
    def bubble_sort(x):
        n = len(x)
    
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n - i - 1):
    
                if x[j][0] < x[j + 1][0]:
                    x[j], x[j + 1] = x[j + 1], x[j]
    
        return x
    
    def no_symbols(x):
        if x in "(¬!”£$%^&*()-_)":
            print("You’ve entered an invalid character")
            exit()
    
    
    while i != 0:
    
        total = 0
    
        name = str(input(print("Please enter the student's name.")))
    
        no_symbols(name)
    
        grade = float(input(print("Please enter the student's grade for the 1st term.")))
    
        grade2 = float(input(print("Please enter the student's grade for the 2nd term.")))
    
        grade3 = float(input(print("Please enter the student's grade for the 3rd term.")))
    
        total = float(grade+grade2+grade3)/3
    
        print("Final Grade:", round(total, 2),"||||", "Student Name:", name ,"\n")
    
        record = (total,name)
    
        list_organizer(record)
    
        print("\n||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||\n")
    
        i = int(input(print("Press 1 to enter another student else press 0 to see results")))
    
        print("||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||")
    
        print("List A", bubble_sort(listA))
        print("List B", bubble_sort(listB))
        print("List C", bubble_sort(listC))
        print("List D", bubble_sort(listD))
```

Comment: What's `gradinglist`? What error occurs? Are you talking about the undefined variable?

Comment: You have an undefined function `gradinglist()`

Comment: I've added it but it just prints the list

Comment: To start with (i.e. ther are other erros), but why do you have both record = {total: name} and l = [dict(zip([total], [name])) for x in range(1, 2)]? You probably just want `record = (name, total)` meaning just a tuple since its a simpler data structure that serves your needsd..

Comment: I've added this update but still can find a way to sort the tuple once the list is formed

Comment: This has solved the issued Ive updated the code to reflect this